# Error while creating a look up field on Property in Activity while following Trail of Admin Beginner - Create Object-Specific Quick Actions

Tags: contact, event, activities

I am following the trail for Admin Beginner and came across the error as "There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Lookups on activities must have a unique domain. You cannot have multiple relationships to the same object."." I have followed every instruction on the trail (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_objectspecific?trail_id=force_com_admin_beginner).
Did I miss any step to get this error? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check for the deleted fields in Activity object. If there is a deleted field erase it and create lookup again.
If you are unable to view deleted field switch to Classic UI and check there.